# How to create multiple many-to-many relationships with only one-sided navigation properties using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first

I have two tables mapped to POCO entities with Entity Framework's code first API.

The tables are `CatalogValue` and `Person`.

I want to create 2 many-to-many relationship between these tables via the navigation properties of Person: `Addresses` and `Organisations`.

I have to mention that I don't want to add a navigation property to `CatalogValue`.

This is my current code:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
             .HasMany(a => a.Addresses)
             .WithOptional()
             .Map(c =>
             {
                  c.ToTable("PersonAddressMapping");
             });

 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
             .HasMany(a => a.Organisations)
             .WithOptional()
             .Map(c =>
             {
                  c.ToTable("PersonOrganisationMapping");
             });
```

Here is the error which I get:

```
The specified table 'PersonAddressMapping' was not found in the model. 
Ensure that the table name has been correctly specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your use of `WithOptional()` is incorrect here. To configure a many-to-may you would use `WithMany()` after your `HasMany()`. You still don't have to specify a collection. Try configuring like this.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
         .HasMany(a => a.Addresses)
         .WithMany()
         .Map(c =>
         {
              c.ToTable("PersonAddressMapping");
         });
```

Comment: I already tried this. It produces this error:

"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Person_dbo.CatalogValue_AddressId' on table 'Person' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."

Comment: The default behaviour is cascade on delete is set to true. Call `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, it fixed the problem. 
For some reason I remembered that you should call WithOptional() if you don't want a navigation property on the other side. But as its name suggests it works only for one-to-many relationships. To sum up: WithMany() without params does the same, but with many-to-many. Thanks!